# open cv multiply crash after distance transform

Tags: multiplication, normalize

hi i perform distance transform the result image has step 4 i want to multiply it by image with step 3 how to do it they have same size

The code:

```
Mat& bwImgIn, Mat& bwImgOut;
distanceTransform(bwImgIn, bwImgOut, distType, maskSize);

Mat colorimg;   
normalize(colorimg, colorimg, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);// iwant image to be beteeen 0-1 is it correct ?


multiply(colorimg, bwImgOut, d1); //crash
colorimg 200*100 , dims=2 , step 300,3
bwImgOut 200*100  , dims 2, step 400,4  --> not same !!!
```

Comment: then what is your problem??

Comment: multipy return exception

Comment: i use the example code now its not crashing , but i dont understand how it was step 4 and now what is this code exacly code:      distanceTransform(bwImgIn, bwImgOut, distType, maskSize);
 //imwrite("bwImgOut.jpg", bwImgOut);

 Mat dist32s, dist8u1, dist8u2;

 bwImgOut.convertTo(dist32s, CV_32S, 1, 0.5);
 dist32s &= Scalar::all(255);

 dist32s.convertTo(dist8u1, CV_8U, 1, 0);
 dist32s *= -1;

 dist32s += Scalar::all(255);
 dist32s.convertTo(dist8u2, CV_8U);

 Mat planes[] = { dist8u1, dist8u2, dist8u2 };
 merge(planes, 3, bwImgOut);